# SQL query, using IN and LIKE at the same time. Possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hope you can help me.

I have a MySQL query to fetch advertisements from my `ads` table by search keyword using the `LIKE` option while trying to fetch for only certain advertisement owners, aka `userId`'s.

My code goes like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.userId as adOwnerId, a.name, a.phoneNumber, a.categoryId, a.cityId, a.description, a.dateCreated, a.dateModified
FROM ads a

INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = a.categoryId
INNER JOIN categories_lang cl ON c.id = cl.categoryId

WHERE a.name LIKE '%someKeyword%'
OR a.description LIKE '%someKeyword%'
OR cl.name LIKE '%someKeyword%'
AND a.userId IN (9, 6, 5, 12, 8, 2)

ORDER BY a.dateCreated DESC
```

My problem is, the `IN` clause just doesn't work, at all.
Although, if I remove those lines:

```
OR a.description LIKE '%someKeyword%'
OR cl.name LIKE '%someKeyword%'
```

Then it works great.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses to protect the `AND` from the `OR`s:

```
(
    a.name LIKE '%someKeyword%'
    OR a.description LIKE '%someKeyword%'
    OR cl.name LIKE '%someKeyword%'
)
AND a.userId IN (9, 6, 5, 12, 8, 2)
```

Otherwise, you have this:

```
A OR B OR C AND D
```

which by default is the same as this:

```
A OR B OR (C AND D)
```

which means the whole expression is true as long as either `A` or `B` is true.

---

Because of the title of the question, I'm also going to extend my answer for others who may arrive here looking at a different problem. Often, someone asking about mixing `IN()` and `LIKE` is try doing to do something like this:

```
WHERE column INLIKE ('x%', 'y%', 'z%')
```

instead of:

```
WHERE column LIKE 'x%' OR column LIKE 'y%' OR column LIKE 'z%'
```

Of course, there is no such thing as an `INLIKE` operator. To get around this, I often tell them to put the values into a derived table, and join to the table with a LIKE expression:

```
 with inlike as 
 select <columnlist> 
 from myTable t
 inner join 
    (select 'x%' as val union select 'y%' union select 'z%') u
    on t.column like u.val
```

The trick here is to make sure either that the join condition can only match at most one possible entry from the derived table for each record in the source table, or that you use a GROUP BY or other mechanism (`APPLY`/`LATERAL` can do this, but only modern DB engines — MySql has fallen **way** behind the ansi standard and no longer qualifies — support them) to limit to the first match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your ORed statements in parentheses:

```
SELECT a.id, a.userId as adOwnerId, a.name, a.phoneNumber, a.categoryId, 
  a.cityId, a.description, a.dateCreated, a.dateModified
FROM ads a
  INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = a.categoryId
  INNER JOIN categories_lang cl ON c.id = cl.categoryId
WHERE (
  a.name LIKE '%someKeyword%'
  OR a.description LIKE '%someKeyword%'
  OR cl.name LIKE '%someKeyword%'
)
AND a.userId IN (9, 6, 5, 12, 8, 2)
ORDER BY a.dateCreated DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you use parentheses to specify order of conditions.

Example below:

```
(
    a.name LIKE '%someKeyword%' 
    OR a.description LIKE '%someKeyword%')
    OR cl.name LIKE '%someKeyword%' 
)
AND a.userId IN (9, 6, 5, 12, 8, 2)
```

You must know what is your priority on search.

Comment: To elaborate to OP, your `X OR Y OR Z AND A` is the equivalent of `X OR Y OR (Z AND A)`